# Symfony REST api. Do I need forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm building a simple API using Symfony4. The question is do I need to use Symfony Form component, or better way is just get data from response?
I saw different examples on different resourses.

And... If I should use Form Component, how to fetch data from response to form? It's not happens automatically. Is it `$form->subimt($request->request->all())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use form, it always depends what you want to achieve.

`$form->subimt($request->request->all())` should be `$form->handleRequest($request);`.

*Remember that fields need to have the same name in the form and on frontend if you want to automatically match data.*

You can try https://api-platform.com/